# What is the meaning of this 将？

Tags: meaning

This 将 indicates A. 'just before' or B. 'just after' sunset? zdic.net has

1. 将： 快要， ‘just about to' so A
2. 将： 刚，刚刚 which I think means 'just happened', so B

那是一个夕阳将落的傍晚，.....

Comment: There must be a mistake in the sentence. 将 means 'will' , 快要 means 'soon be' and 刚/刚刚 means 'has just' : "那是一个夕阳将落的傍晚"( this is a nightfall which the setting sun will go down ) make no sense

Comment: http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/characters/827/ 将 doesn't has the meaning of  刚，刚刚

Comment: I don't think 將 has the meaning "just happened". What is your source that claims this?

Comment: http://www.zdic.net/z/18/js/5C06.htm 1. 快要 12. 刚，刚刚

Comment: In every "傍晚", "夕阳" will always "落" within a short period of time.  What does the writer want to say??

Comment: 说‘傍晚’你觉得日肯定还没落下呢？英语的‘dusk’不一定还可以看到日。作家要说‘at dusk'. 我问： 将的意思是日已经下落或者仍然可看到。不这么重要，我好奇而已。

Answer (score 4):

將 = about to = will soon

"In the evening, the moment the Sun was about to set," [...I suppose the sentence is unfinished]

edit: right, I am reminded that (slightly old-fashioned sense) 將 has the sense of 了, but that is not equivalent to 剛剛. "了" means something similar to perfect tense, but that does not necessarily happen "just before now".

Comment: This is not a very elaborate answer but sounds reasonable to me. +1

Answer (score 2):

> 2. 将： 刚，刚刚

I think it means the aspect marker 將 (similar to 了-- indicating completed action )

Example:

When '將' is placed directly after a verb,  it is acting as an 'aspect marker' that indicating completed action. Similar to '了', which is more common in modern Chinese.

You can say '將' is an archaic form of '了'

Examples:

- 敵兵殺**將**過來 = 敵兵殺**了**過來 (Enemy soldiers have charged at us)
- 一拳打**將**出去 = 一拳打**了**出去 (launched one punch away)

The term '剛/剛剛' = adverb 'just' in English. It needs to be placed directly before the verb.

Examples:

- 敵兵**剛剛**殺過來 = Enemy soldiers **have just** charged at us
- 一拳**剛剛**打出去 = one punch **has just** launched away

> "那是一个夕阳**将**落的傍晚"
>
> "That was a nightfall which the setting sun **was about** to go down."

*Since '将' here is placed before the verb '落', it can only be the adverb 'soon' or 'about to' (*1. 将： 快要， ‘just about to'*)

Answer (score 0):

I am a Chinese student. "将" indicates 1. adv. about to or (sometimes means do sth right now). for example: 将来，我将去美国旅游。 In the future, I will travel to the USA. 2. n.  general. 将军被解除了最高指挥官的职务。 The general was relieved of his office as a supreme commander.